# How do I exclude canvas element from Blazor Server page when modifying DOM from js?

Tags: javascript, c#, canvas, razor, blazor

I have a canvas tag which I update only using js logic. But after the first update, the canvas element is moved to the bottom of the html tree (guess it's a razor's fallback strategy when DOM is changed outside and it internal representation doesn't match). It would be nice to use something like:

```
@excludeFromRender { <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas> }
```

What options do I have to update canvas element in the middle of page from js (meaning client-side) and keep it in right place of page? I should note that it's mandatory to use Blazor Server.

I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: If it is mandatory to use blazor, then why is the canvas not being updated using blazor? My own solution would be to use to the one methodology to avoid creating spaghetti code.

Comment: _"... is moved to the bottom of the html tree"_ is not what shoul;d normally happen. Post the surrounding code and preferably create a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the element would be moved to the bottom of the tree.

Here's a simple wrapper component to do your `excludeFromRender`. It only renders once when the page loads:

```cs
    public sealed class RenderOnce : IComponent
    {
        private RenderFragment _renderFragment;
        private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
        private bool _hasNeverRendered = true;

        [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

        public RenderOnce()
        {
            _renderFragment = builder =>
            {
                _hasNeverRendered = false;
                builder.AddContent(0, ChildContent);
            };
        }

        public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
            => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

        public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
            if (_hasNeverRendered)
                _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Then use it like this:

```cs
<RenderOnce>
 <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</RenderOnce>
```

Comment: Nice, but I can't think of a real use-case here. This should be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured what was wrong in my case. I simply forgot to remove `document.body.appendChild(canvas);` at the end of canvas update logic. Sorry to bother.